# Using styled JTextfField multiple times? (java)

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, styles, jtextfield

I want to have 3 different textfields that should use the same styling,

```
txt = new JTextField();
txt.setText("Room floor number");
txt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
txt.setEditable(false);
txt.setColumns(10);
txt.setBorder(null);
txt.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
```

Now what i want is another textfield with these settings applied by inheritance?
Like in CSS, you can use:

```
textfield textfield1 {
- code1 -
- code2 -
}
textfield textfield1 textfield2 {
- code3 -
}
```

Not sure if this is correct but you get the deal,
here textfield2 gets code1 and code2 and then adds (could replace aswell) code3 to only the textfield2.

So basically i want to use txt style for lets say txt2 and txt3.
I could just txt2 everything but thats not optimal now is it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but not quite the way your thinking.  You have at least two options...

### You Could

Write a method that takes a `JTextField` and applies the changes you want...

```
public void applyFormat(JTextField field) {
    txt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    txt.setEditable(false);
    txt.setColumns(10);
    txt.setBorder(null);
    txt.setBackground(Color.GRAY);    
}
```

### Or You Could

Write a factory method that generates a new `JTextField` with the required formatting applied...

```
public JTextField createFormattedField() {
    JTextField txt = new JTextField();
    txt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    txt.setEditable(false);
    txt.setColumns(10);
    txt.setBorder(null);
    txt.setBackground(Color.GRAY);    
    return txt;
}
```

For example...

Comment: Okay, how would i use these methods?

pane.add(createFormattedField()) ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Personally, because you need to supply some more details to each field, I would use something like `JTextField txt = createFormattedField();` and the you could customise it further, for example `txt.setText("Room floor number");`

Comment: Thanks! It worked! How do I seperate them though? Like an ID?
lets say I want to have a Reset button for these textfields,
txt.setText(""); for resetting. How would that be done?

Comment: You have a number of options, you could simply maintain individual references to each field you create, or if you have lots of them, put them into an array...